# What is wrong with this apache url htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've got this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/redir?url=(.*)$ http://blah.$1
```

When I use this and go to the url that looks like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/redir?url=www.otherdomain.com
```

It says the file isn't found on my server.  I.E. no redirect.

What I want it to do in the above example would be to redirect to:

```
http://blah.www.otherdomain.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriterules don't work on querystrings, RewriteCond's do:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=([^&]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?redir$ http://blah.%1
```